# Step in Python Lettuce. Is it possible to prepend step.hashes headers in step code?

Tags: lettuce

Currently I'm writting some integration tests in Python Lettuce. I want to create a generic step for some XML's comparision.

I know that in .feature file after step definition like

```
Scenario: I want to compare XML's...
 ...
 And I check generated transaction "XYZ" contents with parameters:
 ...
```

I can add step.hashes, which would be available in step.hashes property in step definition (some_step_definitions.py bellow)

```
@step(u'And I check generated transaction "([^"]+)" contents with parameters:$')
def check_generated_content(step, transaction_type):
    *(some xml mappings for comparision, appending dictionaries to step.hashes)*
    for item in mappings:
       step.hashes.append({
          'key1': 'val1',
          'key2': 'val2'
       })
```

My question is: Is it possible to append headers (key1, key2) in step code (check_generated_content), that when tests are executed I have headers in test report like:

```
Scenario: I want to compare XML's...
 ...
 And I check generated transaction "XYZ" contents with parameters:
| key1 | key2 |
| val1 | val2 |
...
```

When I dont specify

```
And I check generated transaction "XYZ" contents with parameters:
| key1 | val1 |
```

in feature file, I get in test report:

```
And I check generated transaction "XYZ" contents with parameters:
| | |
| | |
```

In conclusion.. I would like to write only

```
And I check generated transaction "XYZ" contents with parameters:
```

instead of

```
And I check generated transaction "XYZ" contents with parameters:
| key1 | val1 |
```

every time.

Comment: Ok I need to answer my question instead commenting it :)

Answer (score 0):

So in meantime when writting this, I've came up with solution. It was pretty easy...
in step code definition what I needed to add were default values for step keys

```
step.keys = [ 'key1', 'val1' ]
```

Then I could append hashes to step.hashes. After that I've executed step with behave_as method

```
step.behave_as(step.sentence + '\n' + step.represent_hashes())
```

And everything was beautifully printed in test output.

Comment: step.keys = ['key1', 'key2'] is sufficient